# Ruby on rails migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I initially ran a migration when I created the database and everything worked fine. Then I went and deleted the table in postgresql manually. Now when I run rake db:migrate, it runs but doesn't create the table.

Comment: Yes it won't work as those migrations already executed. Rails will execute only those that are not previously executed. Only way is to rollback and run migrations again.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your migrations do. `rake db:migrate` can create or change tables, depending on your definitions. To setup the database and the tables in the beginning you can use `rake db:schema:load` or `rake db:setup`. `rake -T` gives an overview over all available rake tasks.

Database migrations are stored in the table `schema_migrations` which has one column `version`. As long as the version of the migration in question can be found here, the migration is not executed again.

Comment: It's the exact same migration as before. It creates a table. Then I deleted the table in the database and I want to create it again.

Comment: There is a table `schema_migrations` which may contain the version already. I have updated the answer accordingly.